# Is there any one who can explain the setTag of android view?

Tags: android, view, android-listview, tags

I understood setTag to use store view information generally in list adapter.

below is the codes one of them.

```
public class ViewHolder {
    // I added a generic return type to reduce the casting noise in client code
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends View> T get(View view, int id) {
        SparseArray<View> viewHolder = (SparseArray<View>) view.getTag();
        if (viewHolder == null) {
            viewHolder = new SparseArray<View>();
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        View childView = viewHolder.get(id);
        if (childView == null) {
            childView = view.findViewById(id);
            viewHolder.put(id, childView);
        }
        return (T) childView;
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering yet, what happening inside of view.setTag(viewHolder); Because It had set before viewHolder.put(id, childview); how is it storing them?

Comment: A ViewHolder object stores each of the component views inside the tag field of the Layout, so you can immediately access them without the need to look them up repeatedly. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: did you wrote it without understanding what did you actually wrote?

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks, But My question is how childView stored on viewHolder. Although It had put after view set viewHolder as a Tag.

Comment: @blackbelt This is not my codes. I brought it here: http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: @yountae.kang you might want to check this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18273

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks, but it seems the talk about memory leak of setTag(key, obj) not setTag(obj)

Comment: @yountae.kang why are you worried about it. i guess it an internal implementation of getview coz romain says The new implementation uses a SparseArray local to each View instance instead of a static WeakHashMap. using view holder pattern mentioned in the docs should be enough.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes. you're right. It is enough to use. I just want to know more :)

Comment: @yountae.kang view.setTag(holder) stored entire object of ViewHolder as tag and second time it extract already stored object from it by using view.getTag(). it prevent the regular initilization of view because it not needed all time so it is affect the overall performance of listView or etc.. when view has a large data.

Comment: @Hardik above codes, the viewholder stored before set the childview. but how to childview is re-used later?

Comment: @yountae.kang when function called the first time view.getTag() return null so viewHoder==null will true and set the view.settag(holder). and second time it will restore the holder by view.getTag(). and viewHolder is reference so its does't matter  that you are putting data (viewHolder.put(id, childview)) after setting tag (view.setTag(holder)).

Comment: @Hardik you mean setTag(obj) just store the object's reference?

Comment: yes its stored you whole object for reuse as a tag